# SQL - How to group a column based on another column

Tags: sql

I would like to group by the column "ID" but concatenate the column "Country" separated by a comma. Is that even possible?

Main table sample:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | US |
| 02 | BR |
| 02 | CR |

**Expectation:**

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | US |
| 02 | BR,CR |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Duplicate and no RDMS specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DBMS you're using, there are different functions that can be employed to solve your problem. In general it belongs to the class of the aggregation functions, and as such, it requires a column you want to aggregate on (in your case `Country`) and optionally a column you want to group on (in your case `ID`).

---

Given [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), [SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) official documentation, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function:

```
SELECT ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Country)
FROM tab 
GROUP BY ID
```

Try [MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scAsuEFh6dHN6MbP6ejYb3/0), [SQLite](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cioKbrDCe7x3MxhRRvEQvY/0) or [MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5009f1da5d966a685b62225363857b05) demo at the corresponding links.

---

Given [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html) and [SQLServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) official documentation, you can use the `STRING_AGG` aggregation function:

```
SELECT ID,
       STRING_AGG(Country, ',')
FROM tab 
GROUP BY ID
```

Try [PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c9m42yg6Q7Yu2AD2BMhg1K/0) or [SQLServer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0db64a5007f6f2f04e369c86dd22fb32) demo at the corresponding links.

---

Given [OracleDB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) official documentation, you can use the `LISTAGG` aggregation function:

```
SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(Country, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Country) Country
FROM tab 
GROUP BY ID
```

Try [OracleDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0056347ad612a7d0499dd5f500e18e08) demo at the corresponding link.

---

Hopefully this is comprehensive enough to help future people to aggregate on strings with the most popular databases.